AWS RDS Aurora MySQL 5.7 upgrade to MySQL 8 failed with error: The 'InnoDB' feature is disabled; you need MySQL built with 'InnoDB' to have it working
We have an AWS RDS Aurora 2 (MySQL 5.7) cluster with one writer instance and one reader instance that we are trying to upgrade to Aurora 3 (MySQL 8). When trying to upgrade the upgrade fails and the following error gets logged in multiple places in the upgrade-prechecks.log log file: The 'InnoDB' feature is disabled; you need MySQL built with 'InnoDB' to have it working.
I have checked the engine with the SHOW ENGINES query and 'InnoDB' is listed and is marked as the 'DEFAULT' (see below)
hmapi> SHOW ENGINES;
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA     | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------+------------+
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES    | YES        |
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO     | NO         |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO     | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO     | NO         |
| MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                          | NO           | NO     | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO     | NO         |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO     | NO         |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                             | NO           | NO     | NO         |
| FEDERATED          | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | <null>       | <null> | <null>     |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------+------------+

I have queried the tables with the following query (SELECT TABLE_NAME, ENGINE FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'hmapi') as well to see if there was any table that was using a different engine but all of the tables were showing 'InnoDB'. I have checked both the writer and reader instance.
Here are some of the upgrade-prechecks.log entries if that helps:
{
            "id": "schemaInconsistencyCheck",
            "title": "Schema inconsistencies resulting from file removal or corruption",
            "status": "ERROR",
            "description": "The 'InnoDB' feature is disabled; you need MySQL built with 'InnoDB' to have it working"
        },
        {
            "id": "engineMixupCheck",
            "title": "Tables recognized by InnoDB that belong to a different engine",
            "status": "ERROR",
            "description": "The 'InnoDB' feature is disabled; you need MySQL built with 'InnoDB' to have it working"
        },
        {
            "id": "auroraGetDanglingFulltextIndex",
            "title": "Tables with dangling FULLTEXT index reference",
            "status": "ERROR",
            "description": "The 'InnoDB' feature is disabled; you need MySQL built with 'InnoDB' to have it working"
        },
        {
            "id": "getMismatchedMetadata",
            "title": "Column definition mismatch between InnoDB Data Dictionary and actual table definition.",
            "status": "ERROR",
            "description": "The 'InnoDB' feature is disabled; you need MySQL built with 'InnoDB' to have it working"
        },

Any help around this is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
We tried upgrading from AWS RDS Aurora 2 (MySQL 5.7.12) to Aurora 3 (MySQL 8.0.32) but the upgrade failed.

When you upgrade AWS RDS aurora Mysql version, if you have error, you can select other option for solution.
Simply, you can new instance with version to upgrade in console.
then you backup database from old version and you can import to new version.
Regard.

We've considered that option and will probably will have to go that route unless someone else might have any other ideas. We would prefer to go through the update/migration process to ensure that our data has been checked prior to updating.
